# Why Use TOTP/HOTP instead of just using math.random()?

Tags: android, node.js, one-time-password

I'm trying to add OTP functionality for sign in, in my android app. I'm using node.js for the backend. Now, first I thought about generating random numbers like `math.random()`.

I can easily generate PTPs on my server side and I will store them in my MongoDB datastore then I'll match them when user enter the OTP, but now I came across these prebuild modules for OTP this one Speakeasy https://www.npmjs.com/package/speakeasy.

There are two types of methods HOTP/TOTP. I am asking why would anyone use these two and just not using random numbers.I mean what are the use of HOTP/TOTP? If anybody has designed OTP functionality in any app/website please enlighten me.

**UPDATE**
What is the general way of OTP authentication on any android device from the server I mean apps like zomato, Airbnb how do they do OTP verification of the user?

Comment: `math.random` isn't random; it's pseudorandom, and not cryptographically secure.

Comment: can you please tell what does this synchronization mean in totp i mean client is my android phone and server is using node.js

Comment: So you'd show the return value of `Math.random()` to the user and the user would send it to the server? How would the server verify that the number  is correct / valid?

Comment: i am storing it in my mongodb database

Comment: So the user has to simply come up with a random number and hope it matches one you previously generated? Or how would the user know which number to type?

Comment: u dont get it i will generate it on my server and send it to user's phone and from there it will send on the server to match, got it ??

Comment: please help me @FelixKling if i am doing anything wrong also can you please help me tell what is the correct process of this otp authentication on any android device from the server?? it will be really helpful for me

Comment: I think the big piece you are missing is this: the otp tokens are generated *independently* on the client *and* the server. There is no communication between the client and server. Later when the user sends the token to the server, the server verifies whether the client generated the same token. What you are describing doesn't make sense to me. Why would I tell you the password you have to tell me in order to get some information? in that case there is no need for a password.

Comment: may be seeing that user has the same mobile number which user entered on signup ?? i think this is the reason ??

Answer (score 0):

These OTPs prove "I am in possession of this device that generates OTPs."

In the broadest sense, it could be a statement involving a device that doesn't even have Internet access. HOTP and TOTP are algorithms that you can use offline. Both the device and the server generate the code independently:

```
code = f(shared secret, common info)
```

That shared secret only has to be set up once, e.g. by being baked into a hardware dongle or scanned in a QR code when you set up two-factor authentication. The common info is something that both the server and the dongle can determine each time you log in, e.g. the number of times you've logged in before or the current time and date.

---

Using an actual random number would require your service to deliver that random number to the device. Which if you're developing for an audience that has smartphones, isn't too wild of an idea. Google's two-factor authentication, for example, supports sending a notification to your phone and you just click a button to allow the login.

---

One more thing, a practical consideration: using an existing scheme like TOTP makes it easier for anyone trying to reason about how secure the system is. If they already understand TOTP, they can move on to examining other parts of the system you're building.